# Are RFID/NFC tags and readers compatible? or manufacturer dependent?

Tags: tags, rfid

Are RFID and NFC cards "universally" readable by RFID and NTC readers of the same format/standard? or do they have to be same brand/manufacturer kind of thing as one guy told me?

trying to get into this RFID /NFC thing

regards

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: *they are compatibles.*

RFID uses different standards (ISO all of them):

**18000–2:** Air interface for `135 KHz` <-- LF

**18000–3:** Air interface for `13.56 MHz` <-- HF

**18000–4:** Air interface for `2.45 GHz` <-- Actives

**18000–5:** Air interface for `5.8 GHz` <-- non-commercial

**18000–6**: Air interface for `860 MHz` to `930 MHz` <-- UHF

**18000–7:** Air interface at `433.92 MHz`  <-- non-commercial

If you do some research, you will find some variations like 18000-6C for UHF, etc etc.

---

NFC it's a mixture of several standards as well.

**ISO 14443-4**

**JIS 6319-4**

**ISO 18092**

---

IMO, you should look for interrogators which would read the "standard" per se, and not look for a universal card or reader.